# Androidで自作ライブラリをGradleで利用できるようにしたい

Tags: android, android-studio

```
maven {
  url "https://my.custom.repository/path"
}

...

dependencies {
  ...
  compile 'my.custom.library:library-name:x.x.x@aar'
}
```

のように、自分で作成したAndroidライブラリをGradleで`dependencies`の`compile`に指定するだけで読み込めるようにしたいのですが、どのようにすれば良いのでしょう？
Mavenの公開リポジトリには登録する必要はなく、リポジトリのURLを知っている人だけが使えればよいです。

もしくは、手順を説明しているWebサイトがあれば教えてください。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ライブラリプロジェクト側で、次の記述を追加します。

```
apply plugin: 'maven'

uploadArchives {
    repositories.mavenDeployer {
        // mavenローカルにいれる設定
        repository url: "file://$System.env.HOME/.m2/repository"
        pom.version = '1.0.0'
        pom.groupId = 'com.mokelab'
        pom.artifactId = 'InputDialog-v4'
     }
}

// 通常のライブラリプロジェクトを作る設定が続きます
```

ライブラリプロジェクトのビルドで、次のタスクを実行します。

```
$ sh gradlew clean uploadArchives
```

これで、~/.m2/repositoryにライブラリがインストールされます。この`~/.m2/repository`に生成されたファイルツリーをどこかhttpで見れるところに置くと、質問の通りの指定ができるようになります。

```
maven {
  url "https://my.custom.repository"
}
```

で、上記の例のライブラリを参照可能にするには、次のようなURLでアクセスできるようになっていればOKです。

```
https://my.custom.repository/com/mokelab/InputDialog-v4/1.0.0/InputDialog-v4-1.0.0.aar
https://my.custom.repository/com/mokelab/InputDialog-v4/1.0.0/InputDialog-v4-1.0.0.pom
... その他m2/repositoryに生成される内容
```

Answer (score 0):

[mavenのインハウスリポジトリを作るよ - Qiita](http://qiita.com/NewGyu/items/71b50d036eef64be9b96)

Answer (score 0):

どうしても閉じたネットワーク内に建てる要件でなければbintrayを利用するのが手っ取り早いかと。

閉じたネットワーク内に建てる場合はSonatype Nexusがまさにそんな利用用途です。
nexusはdockerで動かすのが簡単です。
https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/sonatype/nexus/